# java convertable enum

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, enums

I would like to make an enum type that would have a value, and could be converted vice-versa from and to that value (basically the enum would be a type-safe alias for that value, and would imporve code readability).

I need this because I am handling low-level, embedded stuff, and writing registers, and such. 
Many times a few bits of a register have special meanings. Like bit 10-11 of one register is the active CYCCNT
"
  00 - CYCCNT_24, 
  01 - CYCCNT_26, 
  11 - CYCNT_28
"

Now I would like to do something like this:

```
void setActiveCYCCNT(CYCCNT_ENUM newvalue)
{
  Target.writeRegister(ADDRESS, newvalue.value());
}

CYCCNT_ENUM getActiveCYCCNT()
{
  return CYCCNT_ENUM.fromValue(Target.readRegister(ADDRESS));
}
```

I thought doing something like this (but is syntactically incorrect on many levels):

It seems that static members cannot access T. I'm not sure why that is the case, doesn't java generate a new class for each referenced generic type?
Secondly it seems that java does not support generic enums?

```
public enum ConvertableEnum<T> {

    private static Map<T, ConvertableEnum<T>> map = new HashMap<T, ConvertableEnum<T>>();
    T value;

    public ConvertableEnum(T t)
    {
        this.value = t;     
        map.put(t, this);
    }

    public static ConvertableEnum<T> fromValue(T t)
    {
        return map.get(t);
    }

  }
```

After this one could do:

```
public enum CYCCNT : ConvertableEnum<int>
{
  CYCCNT_24(0x00), CYCCNT_26(0x01), CYCCNT_28(0x03);
}
```

And use that.

My question is how can I achieve what I would like to achieve in my syntactically incorrect code?

Thanks for your help,
  axos88

Answer (score 1):

I just did something similar recently:

```
public enum ReferenceType 
{
    SELECT(true),
    INSERT(false),
    SELECT_INTO(false),
    UPDATE(false),
    DELETE(false),
    CREATE_TABLE(false),
    DROP_TABLE(false),
    PRINT(false),
    FROM(false),
    DECLARE(false);

    private final boolean legalSub;

    ReferenceType(boolean _legalSub)
    {
        this.legalSub = _legalSub;
    }

    public boolean isLegalSubstatement()
    {
        return this.legalSub;
    }
}
```

So a ReferenceType ID is e.g. `INSERT` but the (or one of the) associated value is false, which is set in the declaration (`INSERT(false)`) and can be retrieved using isLegalSubstatement().  Similarly, you can have multiple fields associated with every ID, as long as you include them in the constructor respectively.  You can think of each enum item as a row in a reference data table where the ID is the table key and other fields (in the parenths) are columns associated with that key.

Of course, having attributes associated with an enum key is optional, i.e. an enum can be bare simple without any attributes.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: I'm sorry, but no. My problem is converting the other way around, e.g. having the (unique) attribute value, and returning the enum element (of course in order to this the attributes must be unique, and they are).

Comment: in that case you need to create a static collection (e.g. a Map) and populate it in a static block setting the key to the unique attribute and the val to the enum ID.  then you write a getter getEnumIdByUnqAtt(unqAtt) which returns that enum ID by the unique attribute from that collection

Answer (score 1):

Thre is no problem for enum to use an generic interface. Only problme is that enum can not be generic. In addition the GenericVariables must not be pritive so code:

```
    public enum CYCCNT implements ConvertableEnum<Integer>
    {
      CYCCNT_24(0x00), 
      CYCCNT_26(0x01), 
      CYCCNT_28(0x03);

      private int value; 

      CYCCNT(int value) {
        this.value = value;
      }

     public Integer getValue() {
        return this.value;
     }   

    private final static HashMap<Integer,CYCCNT> valueOfMap = new HashMap<Integer,CYCCNT>();  

    static {
      for(CYCCNT cyccnt : CYCCNT.values()) {
         valueOfMap.put(cyccnt.getValue(), cyccnt);
      )
     }
    public static CYCCNT valueOf(int value) {
       return valueOfMap.get(value);
    }
  }
```

Should work

Comment: Hmm.. this seems like a good solution. But I have a question about this: If I have many similar enums, do I have to copy&paste the implementation to each? I just found out the enums can't extend anything...

Comment: @ÁkosVandra, yes you can not inherit or extend enum. You could reorganize the enums that share elements into single ones. But you shold keep in mind that enums should help you to arganize code. IMHO the should not be to large. Your question is really hard to answer as i do not know what you want to store in the enums.

Comment: I'm not referring to sharing elements of the enum, but rather these methods that take care of the conversions.

Answer (score 0):

you could have a function in your enum:

```
public enum CYCCNT /* Should use Camel-case names */
{
  CYCCNT_24, CYCCNT_26, CYCCNT_28;

  public static int toValue(CYCCNT e) {
    switch (e) {
      case CYCCNT_24: return 0x0;
      //...
      default: throw new RuntimeException("Enum value not handled");
    }
  }

  public int toValue() {
    return CYCCNT.toValue(this);
  }
}
```

Else as suggested, you can also put a member variable to save the real value. However I guess this would increase the raw size of the enum instance (not sure about that one though).

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. The goal would be to make it automatic (without having to change anything in the code to add new elements)

Answer (score 0):

AN enum is just a special type of class - enums can have member variables, for example.

So just declare an enum type with each enum having an associated address, plus associated getters and helper functions.

```
public enum CYCCNT_ENUM{
    Value1("a"),
    Value2("b");

    private final String address;

    private CYCCNT_ENUM(String address) {
        this.address= address;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public static CYCCNT_ENUMgetScope(String address) {
        for(CYCCNT_ENUM e : values()){
            if(address.equals(e.getAddress())){
                return e;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Your answer is very similar to that of Vash's. My question is the same. What if I have many enums like this? Do I have to copy&paste the implementation into each? (enum can't extend other classes). Is there a way around this do reduce code duplication?

Answer (score 0):

### Direct solution

`Enum.class` has a method `static <T extends Enum<T>> T valueOf(Class<T> enumType, String name)` that

> returns the enum constant of the specified enum type with the
>   specified name.

Every enum type additionally has a `public static E valueOf(String name)` method.

So by initializing the enum constant with the appropriate value, you have all you need.

### Better solution

Consider `Item 32: Use EnumSet instead of bit fields` from [Josh Bloch's Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683), i.e. the use of the `EnumSet` class directly instead of bit fields might be better.

Comment: This is not correct. The `Enum` class itself (not individual enum types) has a method `public static <T extends Enum<T>> T valueOf(Class<T> enumType, String name)`. Every enum type additionally has a `public static E valueOf(String name)` method.

Comment: This would be a good solution, if the values would be strings, and would be controlled by me. But they are not. I'd still need a hand-initialized map to look up the strings from the integer values, which would defeat the purpose of the solution.